# How can I check for no whitespace before and after a character?

Tags: java, regex

How can I check if there is no whitespace before and after a dot?

Example output's:

```
ABCSF.GHJJKA = true;
ABCSF . GHJJKA = false;
ABCSF. GHJJKA = false;
ABCSF .GHJJKA = false;
ABCSFGHJJKA = false;
ABCSF GHJJKA = false;
```

I use `example.matches();`

Edit:

```
AB CSF.GHJ JKA = true;
AB CSF.GHJJKA = true;
ABCSF.GHJ JKA = true;
```

Comment: Use negative lookarounds, or groups with anchors | negated character classes.

Comment: `\S+\.\S+`..............

Comment: @PranavCBalan: what if the string starts with a dot?

Comment: you can check for 2 regex - dot-space and space dot. it any matches then false

Comment: @PranavCBalan Thanks but I forgot something in my question, that `ABC SF.GHJJKA` or `ABCSF.GHJ JKA` or `ABC SF.GHJ JKA` should also be true

Comment: @Wavum :  `.*\S+\.\S+.*` https://regex101.com/r/lO3iE5/1

Comment: @Wavum My answer still work for your new string also http://stackoverflow.com/a/35910720/5678086

Comment: @Wavum : .`.*\S\.\S.*`

Comment: @PranavCBalan Thanks!

Comment: @Wavum : glad to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below regex to match your requirement

```
 [\w]+\.[\w]+
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the code that will help you determine a whitespace in a
>   string.

***WhiteSpace.java***

```
public class WhiteSpace {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String test_str = "My.name.is.anthony"; //Declare and define a string

    boolean flag = false ; // Initialize boolean variable flag to false

    //For loop that iterates through the entire string 
    for(int  i = 0 ; i < test_str.length() ; i++ ){

        if(Character.isWhitespace(test_str.charAt(i))){ //check whether the current character is a white space

            flag = true;
            break;  //Breaks as soon as the first white space is encountered
        }
    }
    if(flag == true ){

        System.out.println("The string has a white space!!");

    }else{
        System.out.println("No white space!!");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Check the above program with a space in  between.